# How to convert an IPv6 address from decimal number string to two bigints in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ipv6, bigint

I have a CSV file containing IPv6 addresses that I'm trying to bulk import into a sql server table. An example of an address in the CSV file might be "55828295930114724823525874468560830464". I'd like the IP address to be stored into two bigints in the database, seeing as SQL bigint can handle just 64-bits whereas the IPv6 address requires 128-bits. My import code for handling IPV4 addresses is:

```
SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO dbo.IPCountry
    SELECT
        REPLACE(ipFROM, ''"'', '''') AS ipFROM,
        REPLACE(ipTO, ''"'', '''') AS ipTO,
        CAST(REPLACE(countrySHORT, ''"'', '''') AS CHAR(2)) AS countrySHORT
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''' + @Directory + 'IPCountry.csv'',
        FORMATFILE = ''' + @Directory + 'IPCountry.Xml''
    ) AS t1
';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

How would I convert the 128-bit IPv6 values as two bigint values?

Comment: I'm guessing that countrySHORT has nothing to do with your converting IPv6 to the bigint's?   Also is ipFROM and ipTO each supposed to be 2 bigint field, IE: ipFROMa and ipFROMb, etc...?

Comment: Correct, countrySHORT is just another value in the CSV file that gets imported into the table. Yes, the IPv6 version will need to split the 128-bit IPv6  value into an upper bigint value and a lower bigint value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example being exactly a 38 character string of digits, I would split it in half and cast each half into the BIGINT component.

Here is an example demonstrating that process and reversing it:

```
-- Prepare test variables
DECLARE @Source AS NVARCHAR(38)
DECLARE @ipFROMa AS BIGINT
DECLARE @ipFROMb AS BIGINT
DECLARE @Destination AS NVARCHAR(38)

SET @Source = '55828295930114724823525874468560830464'

-- Split Source into TWO strings and then each into a BIGINT
SET @ipFROMa = (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@Source,1,19) AS BIGINT))
SET @ipFROMb = (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@Source,20,19) AS BIGINT))

-- Test returning BIGINTs into one IPv6 string
SET @Destination = (SELECT 
                        CAST( 
                            CAST(@ipFROMa AS NVARCHAR(19)) +
                            CAST(@ipFROMb AS NVARCHAR(19))
                             AS nvarchar(38)))

-- Display the values for verification
SELECT @Source, @ipFROMa, @ipFROMb, @Destination
```

**RESULTS:**

> 55828295930114724823525874468560830464    5582829593011472482 3525874468560830464 55828295930114724823525874468560830464

Comment: Don, this works well if I'd simply need to store the 128-bit value in two bigints without needing to perform any math on them, eg. looking for a value (countrySHORT) that falls between ipFROM and ipTO. IPv6 needs to be split into its upper 64-bit value and lower 64-bit value. So, using your example ipFROMa would contain the lower 64-bit value of IPv6 and ipFROMb would contain the upper 64-bit value of IPv6.

Comment: IPv6 addresses are usually written in eight groups of four hexadecimal digits separated by colons.
They are divided into two parts: a 64-bit (sub-)network prefix and a 64-bit interface identifier.
However it appears you are retrieving them as whole Decimal numbers.
Provided the original HEX to Decimal conversion maintained the most significant digits to the left,
then splitting it exactly in half as I did above, should result in:
ipFROMa should be the "(sub-)network prefix" 
and ipFROMb should be the "interface identifier" 
However, they're just not in the normal HEX formatting.